# SSIS Conditional split handling nulls and other values in column

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

I have an SSIS package in 2010

I want to return any nulls in a column or a value in the same column

This using the conditional split

I have the first part

```
ISNULL([Data Conversion].ID)== TRUE
```

this will bring me all the null ID rows

but I want to add a OR part

I am looking for something like  :

```
ISNULL([Data Conversion].ID)== TRUE && [Data Conversion].ID =="ABC"
```

what replaces the && to achieve the OR condition please - or how to amend the code to achieve the OR condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[|| (Logical OR) (SSIS Expression)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/logical-or-ssis-expression?view=sql-server-ver15) : Performs a logical OR operation. The expression evaluates to TRUE if one or both conditions are TRUE.

```
(ISNULL([Data Conversion].ID) == TRUE || [Data Conversion].ID =="ABC" ) && [Data Conversion].Sex =="Male"
```